# help with python inheritance

Tags: python, django

Given an arbitrary object:

```
class Val(object):
    def __init__(self):
        this_val = 123
```

I want to create an abstract base class which has an attribute that is a `Val()`:

```
class A(object):
    foo = Val()
```

I would expect that when my children inherit from that class, they would get copies of `Val()`. For example:

```
class B(A):
    pass
class C(A):
    pass
```

I would expect the following behavior:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> c = C()
>>> c.foo.this_val = 456
>>> b.foo.this_val
123
```

But instead I get:

```
>>> b.this_val
456
```

I understand that I could just `self.foo = Val()` into the **init** to achieve that behavior, but I have a requirement that foo remain an attribute (it is a model manager in django). Can anyone suggest a work around for this?

**EDIT:** I really need to be able to access the value as a class attribute, so my desired behavior is:

```
>>> C.foo.this_val = 456
>>> B.foo.this_val
123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using a [descriptor](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) would suit your requirements:

```
class Val(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.this_val = 123

class ValDesc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cls_lookup = {}

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.cls_lookup.setdefault(objtype, Val())

class A(object):
    foo = ValDesc()

class B(A):
    pass
class C(A):
    pass
```

Now, as long as you make sure you don't set the instance attribute "foo" of any of your objects, they will have a class attribute that is individual to each subclass:

```
b = B()
c = C()
cc = C()
c.foo.this_val = 456
print c.foo.this_val   # 456
print cc.foo.this_val  # 456
print b.foo.this_val   # 123
```

**EDIT:** With the edit I made some hours ago, changing the key in `__get__` to be `objtype` instead of `obj.__class__`, this also works when accessing the class attributes directly:

```
print B.foo.this_val   # 123
print C.foo.this_val   # 456
```

Answer (score 4):

The attribute `foo` *only* exists on `A`. You will have to use a metaclass to add a new `Val` to each class.

```
class Val(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.this_val = 123

class MC(type):
  def __init__(self, name, bases, d):
    super(MC, self).__init__(name, bases, d)
    self.foo = Val()

class A(object):
  __metaclass__ = MC

class B(A):
  pass

B.foo.this_val = 456
print A.foo.this_val
print B.foo.this_val
```

Answer (score 0):

Do both.

Make it a class attribute, but also initialize it to a fresh instance in the `__init__` function. That way the reference stored isn't a shared one.

Comment: I need to reference it as an attribute, though. I want to do `C.foo.this_val` and `B.foo.this_val` and get different results. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I have no instance :(

Comment: Override it in the individual class definition(s) then?

Comment: I had really hoped not to. There must be some obscure python private method that I can override to achieve this?

Comment: Er, even if there were, it'd be more complex than just overriding it in the class defs...